# use external json as metadata for fungible asset

Tags: mint, fungible-token, metaboss, json

I hope my question is clear.

So far I have been using metaboss to create fungible assets, which seemingly requires that I create local json files for the metadata.

Is it possible to point it to an json endpoint to source the metadata?

Here is the command I have been using

```
metaboss create fungible -d 0 -m mol.json --initial-supply 100
```

In place of the local mol.json file, I would like to use an endpoint, but no joy so far.

Is there a way?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The metaboss tool does not support that at the moment.

Your best bet will be to send a PR to add the functionality, here's the repo: https://github.com/samuelvanderwaal/metaboss.

The `-m` only accepts a file, but you could easily change it to interpret a URL! Here's the line you'll need to change: https://github.com/samuelvanderwaal/metaboss/blob/1661ffcb71e83b287fd4a6591d83811f68f174da/src/create/methods.rs#L124